# splitting one line into two when creating a Text Editor

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, memory-management

```
void splitLine(Document *document, location loc) {

    char* newLine = malloc(loc.idx * sizeof(char) + 1);
    char* origLine = strdup(Document_get_line(document, loc.line_no));
    char* nextLine = malloc((strlen(origLine)-loc.idx) * sizeof(char) + 1);

    newLine = strncpy(newLine, origLine, loc.idx);
    newLine[loc.idx] = '\0';

    nextLine = strncpy(nextLine, origLine+loc.idx, strlen(origLine)-loc.idx);
    nextLine[strlen(origLine)-loc.idx] = '\0';


    Document_set_line(document, loc.line_no, newLine);
    Document_insert_line(document, loc.line_no+1, nextLine);   

    free(newLine);
    free(nextLine);
    free(origLine);

    newLine = NULL;
    nextLine = NULL;
    origLine = NULL;

}
```

This code is used to split the 'loc.line_no'th line in 'document' at the 'loc.idx'th character into two parts, but I am having hard time following the code especially from the fourth line of the function. Please help me follow what each line of the code does.

Comment: There's only one function you should learn to understand this code, and that's strncpy. Did you read what it does? It's std C library function. Mind that assigning '\0' to end of a char array is to make it a null terminated string - to make it suitable for all string manipulation functions.

Comment: The fouth/fifth and sixth/seventh line pairs are copying the two parts of the split text to temporary locations. The first line of each pair uses the function `strncpy` which protects against buffer overflow. The second of each pair writes a precautionary string terminator `'\0'` because `strncpy` does not always do this. The first part of the split line then replaces the exisiting line in the text document, and the second part is inserted as a new text line. Then the temporary storage is `free`d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
char* newLine = malloc(loc.idx * sizeof(char) + 1);
char* origLine = strdup(Document_get_line(document, loc.line_no));
char* nextLine = malloc((strlen(origLine)-loc.idx) * sizeof(char) + 1);
```

we dynamically allocated temporary space, in which our operations will take place. Notice that `origLine` context is also initialized to the `loc.line_no`-th line of the Document.

Now read [strncpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/), and then proceed.

`newLine = strncpy(newLine, origLine, loc.idx);` will copy the first `loc.idx` characters of origLine to newLine.

`newLine[loc.idx] = '\0';` null-terminates the string newLine.

Likewise, this:

```
nextLine = strncpy(nextLine, origLine+loc.idx, strlen(origLine)-loc.idx);
nextLine[strlen(origLine)-loc.idx] = '\0';
```

will copy the first `strlen(origLine)-loc.idx` characters of the substring of `origLine`, that begins at `loc.idx`-th index, to `nextLine`.

So these two parts are copying the two parts of the splitted line to temporary locations (which are valid only inside this function).

These:

```
Document_set_line(document, loc.line_no, newLine);
Document_insert_line(document, loc.line_no+1, nextLine);
```

are custom made function, which are not shown here, but you can guess that the first part of the splitted line replaces the existing line in your Document, and the second part is inserted in the next line, as a new line.

This part:

```
free(newLine);
free(nextLine);
free(origLine);

newLine = NULL;
nextLine = NULL;
origLine = NULL;
```

is for de-allocating the dynamic memory `malloc()` and `strdup()` allocated, and then set the pointers to NULL, for safety reasons.